# What is the modern meaning of the word Ukiyo in Japan today? Is it still used to identify Red Districts or is it only “the floating world” now?

Tags: meaning, kanji

I just really need help knowing the true meaning please.

Comment: *ukiyo* captures a sense of far more than what *red light district* describes in english. when we say red light district, there’s no sense of art being conveyed. ukiyo describes an entire cultural phenomenon that shows up in music, dance, the visual arts, literature, etc. have you researched ukiyo at all? what makes you think it had such a narrow definition?

Comment: 浮き世 in modern Japanese used in non-historical contexts refers to "this modern human world" which 99% of us are familiar with. It does not include "special" or "isolated" part of our society. Places like prisons, army bases, cathedrals, royal palaces and mafia offices are so-called 浮き世離れした場所 (non-浮き世 places). Hardcore red-light districts are also usually considered "non-浮き世" today.

Answer (score 0):

If Red district means Red-light district , no one use Ukiyo for that meaning in modern Japan .